# I need to make a PKI infrastructure, but i don't now how to segment my CA

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority

I'm currently working on a project where we have to rethink a PKI architecture, but we don't know how to segment the different CA_SUBs, do you have any recommendations?

Comment: This is very broad question and it depends on your internal organization, management structure, strategies and so on.

Comment: Yes i know but i'm new to all this stuff, i just want to know if the CA_SUBs  are segmented by the services (like marketing,sales, etc..)

Comment: There is no universal answer. I'm not sure if I've seen segmentation by services. On the other hand, I can't say that it is wrong setup. Some separate them by clients/services (recipients), some divide by key usage (auth/signing/encryption), some divide by region, etc. There are lots of strategies and all are perfect within their scope. Just select what best suites your environment. If you are unsure, I would suggest to address it to consulting services.